# Powershell Set-Acl - Error New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "FileSystemAccessRule" and the argument count: "1"

Tags: arrays, powershell, acl

I'm using the following array to apply permissions to directories but get the error:

New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "FileSystemAccessRule" and the argument count: "1".

```
$psarray = @(
    ('xppusers', 'D:\XPP\xz\bin', 'Read'),
    ('xppusers', 'D:\XPP\xz\sys\config', 'Read'),
    ('xppusers', 'D:\XPP\sd_liz', 'Read'),
    ('xppusers', 'D:\XPP\xz\help', 'Read')
)


foreach($item in $psarray)
{
    $permission = "'" + $item[0] + "', '" + $item[2] + "', 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'"
    $rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permission
    $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
    $acl | Set-Acl -Path $item[1]
}
```

And the full error is:

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "FileSystemAccessRule" and the argument count: "1".
At C:\GPO-Installers\permissions-array.ps1:20 char:13
+     $rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSy ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

If I create the $permission manually it works fine.

eg:

```
$permission = 'xppusers', 'read', 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'
```

Not sure where I have gone wrong and would really appreciate some help.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @mklement0 I've fiddled this and got it working. At some stage when the pressure is off I will go back and understand this properly rather than just copy/pasta my way through the issue.

I've got this working by creating the required variables within the foreach loop and then using these in the New-Object.

```
foreach($item in $UserGroupPermissionArray)
    {     
        $UserGroup = $item[0]
        $Path = $item[1]
        $acl = Get-Acl -Path $Path
        $FileSystemRights = $item[2]
        $InheritanceFlag = "ContainerInherit"
        $PropagationFlag = "None"
        $AccessControlType = "Allow"
        $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($UserGroup, $FileSystemRights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $AccessControlType)
        $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
        $acl | Set-Acl -Path $Path
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistakenly passing a *single string* to the `System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule` constructor (via `New-Object -ArgumentList`); the error implies that there is no constructor (overload) that takes a *single* argument of type `[string]`.<sup>[1]</sup>

Instead, **you must pass constructor arguments *individually*, which in the context of `New-Object` means as an *array*** (`-Args` is an alias for `-ArgumentList`, and you could even omit the `-Args`):

```
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule `
          -Args ($item + 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
```

Since `$item` is an array containing the first 2 constructor arguments, you can simply use array concatenation (`+`) to append<sup>[2]</sup> the invariant arguments.

---

<sup>[1] The error message can situationally be misleading, since it doesn't explicitly state that it isn't *only* the *count* of arguments that matters, but also the argument's *data type*. For instance, you'd see the same message if there *were* a single-argument constructor, but its argument type were something *other* than `[string]`.</sup>

<sup>[2] Technically, a *new* array is created that is the concatenation of the elements from the input arrays.</sup>

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried working through this and had so many issues. But I have resolved it by creating the required variables in the foreach loop and then using these in the New-Object. 

$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($UserGroup, $FileSystemRights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $AccessControlType)

Comment: Glad to hear you your problem, @DigitalEssence; note that you don't strictly need the `(...)` around the array elements (since my solution uses an _expression_ - the array concatenation - `(...)` _is_ needed).